# Aws lambda triggered based on time elapsed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table with an attribute status. how can I trigger a lambda based on how much time elapsed since it last changed? For example if 5 minutes has passed since the Status changed to requested I want to trigger a lambda that sends an alarm. If it changed to from Requested to Initiated ontime but failed to change from Initiated to InProgress in 15 minutes I want to trigger a lambda to send a different alarm.

I have a solution in mind that involves creating a step function but I want to avoid that implementation.

Comment: Have you checked out : [Amazon EventBridge Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/)

Comment: Perhaps use a DynamoDB Streams trigger to write a CloudWatch metric and then configure CloudWatch to [alarm on missing/insufficient data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html#alarms-and-missing-data).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this would be a Step Function even though you don't want to use it, leveraging express workflows (which run for *up* to five minutes) and the WAIT state and using an increment variable to count 1st try, 2nd try, 3rd (final) before firing a lambda function that posts to an SNS topic. You'd have a check-status lambda (which would run in the beginning at right before closing) and a send-alert lambda. Though this still feels messy, as you may send off nasty-grams if someone acted in the last moments 3rd try. It's a lot of polling.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html gives solid guidance on this approach.

To avoid leveraging Step Functions you could go the route of DynamoDB, DynamoDB Streams, EventBridge. Essentially streaming out the changes to the records. https://www.boyney.io/blog/2022-11-03-eventbridge-events-with-dynamodb - this feels a lot cleaner for your purposes.

If it was as simple as scheduling the easiest way nowadays is to leverage EventBridge.

There's two steps:

- Create a Lambda function to execute the scheduled events
- Create an EventBridge rule to run the Lambda function

For a full tutorial you can check out the official AWS docs on scheduling Lambda functions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html